# Google Apps Script - how I can get JSON?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have scripts:

```
function mySheet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getId();
  var name = ss.getName();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetName();
  var maxCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var maxRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(sheetName+"!A1:"+maxCol+maxRow).getValues();

  Logger.log(sheetId +" "+ name +" "+ JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I have values in json, but i need JSON like $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range) return... how I can do that?
i heed data like: `{"majorDimension":"ROWS","range":"'Sheet1'!A1:Z3","values":...}`
I search, but can't find method...

Comment: You seem to want to write in PHP? But this is apps script...its not the same format of API. Maybe zoom out and explain the context of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

User [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets)

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1!A1:Z3`

```js
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), 'Sheet1!A1:Z3')
```

Comment: I try, but I need values only from 1 sheet and other data... i can't see "{ "majorDimension":"ROWS"..."

Comment: THX... How I can send it method POST? GET work but json can be long (more 7000 char)

Comment: Please create a new question and provide more details.